# How to trigger update call from within update

Tags: elm

I've got a situation where I've got two ways to play a musical note within an Elm app, and I keep track of which notes are currently playing. The current code is here:

```
  update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
  update msg model =
      case msg of
          PlayNote note ->
              let
                updatedCurrentPlaying =
                  note :: model.currentPlaying
              in
                ( { model | currentPlaying = updatedCurrentPlaying }, Cmd.none )


          KeyDown keyCode ->
            let
                note =
                  List.filter (\x -> x.keyCode == keyCode) model.notes
                  |> List.head

                updatedCurrentPlaying =
                  case note of
                    Nothing ->
                      model.currentPlaying
                    Just a ->
                      a :: model.currentPlaying
            in
              ( { model | currentPlaying = updatedCurrentPlaying }, Cmd.none )
```

What I want to know is if there is anyway to DRY this up a bit, and cause the `KeyDown` case to trigger a `PlayerNote note` Msg rather than duplication the functionality. I've tried replacing `Cmd.none` with something involving Task and calling update directly but it doesn't seem to work.

Am I going about this the entirely wrong way? Is this not something that's really allowed in elm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that `update` is just a function and can be called like any other function. You can just call it recursively passing the `PlayNote` `Msg`:

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        PlayNote note ->
            let
                updatedCurrentPlaying =
                    note :: model.currentPlaying
            in
            ( { model | currentPlaying = updatedCurrentPlaying }, Cmd.none )


        KeyDown keyCode ->
            let
                note =
                    List.filter (\x -> x.keyCode == keyCode) model.notes
                    |> List.head

            in
            case note of
                Nothing ->
                    ( model, Cmd.none )

                Just a ->
                    update (PlayNote a) model
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I thought I'd tried that but I got into some syntax trouble, much clearer now, thank you!